# How to Remove HTML Elements from Post Excerpt?

Tags: posts, excerpt, content

I am Using the Following Code and want to remove HTML All Elements.

```
<?php $exerpttext = substr(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID), 0, 300);
if (!empty($exerpttext)) { echo $exerpttext.'....'; }  ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this appears to be an XY Problem.

If you simply want to increase the length of the excerpt auto-generated from the post content, you can use the [excerpt_length hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_length/) in functions.php.

```
function modify_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        return 300;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'modify_excerpt_length', 99 );
```

Then simply call the excerpt in your template:

```
the_excerpt()
```

This will automatically remove all tags.

Comment: In this way, do I have to fill the excerpt field or not?

Comment: No. If the except field is not populated, an excerpt will be auto-generated from the post content.